# Is there a way to use Google's Custom Methods with Jersey Resources?

Tags: java, rest, api, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I was looking for a way to make my JAX-RS APIs more readable and came across with Google's Custom Methods approach:

https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/custom_methods

I was looking for this because some of my entities perform more actions than I could express with traditional HTTP verbs. Google pattern is to use a colon (`:`) at the end of the URI, separating the entity/collection from the desired action.

I tried to apply this pattern to a simple Jersey resource, just to test how it could be done. I've got a resource class `StudentDetailsResource` annotated with `@Path("students/{studentId}")` and a few methods also annotated with `@Path`.

If my method has another entity before the custom method, then all is ok. Let's say the enrol method is annotated with 
`@Path("subjects/{subjectId}:enroll")`.

The problem rises when the action is right after the Resource Class URI, because `@Path` uses a URI Template that `prefixWithSlash` all sub-resources. So if I have a dropout method, the annotation would look like `@Path(":dropout")`, but the URI template would become `/students/{studentId}/:dropout`, an this `/:` would break in the matching phase.

I have read about Jersey Providers and ResourceDelegates, but I couldn't find a way to replace the URI Template default action of `prefixWithSlash`.

The question is: how can I apply Google's custom method approach or how can I avoid the default `prefixWithSlash` behaviour with Jersey?

Note: I know this is a silly example and there are other ways to solve this specific case, but I have more complex cases which can benefit from the custom methods.